# Is there a webpack loader that could replace a string with file's path?

Tags: webpack

I'd like to be able to replace a string in a file with this file's path (relative to a project root). Is that possible with webpack? Is there an existing loader for that?

Use case:
I'd like some entities in my code to have these absolute names so I know exactly what they are when they get serialized.

Ideally, I'd like just to be able to write something like `'{PATH}'` and have this string replaced with e.g. `'src/path/to/file.ts'`. Pretty much like DefinePlugin does but with dynamic paths.

Answer (score 2):

My problem can be probably solved by the use of `__filename` and having:

`node: {
        __dirname: true,
        __filename: true
    }`

in webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

maybe create a variable

```
const path = 'src/path/to/'
```

and in webpack example:

```
  {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ],
    include: path.join(__dirname, path + 'folder-style/'),
    exclude: /flexboxgrid/
  },
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood me. I'd like that path to replace the string in every file it encounters it in. There are multiple files, each can be in a different directory - I don't want to list them manually and webpack is already scanning through them all.

Comment: Ok i understandl. There is an option to use a bash script and run it before building. If interested I can tell more.

Comment: You can, but remember that I do want to keep `{PATH}` in source files. Also - the process has to be runnable on mac, windows and linux. Bash script might be problematic here ;]